# How to access XML Node with Special Character from XmlDocument using SelectNodes in c#

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I have following XML:

```
<Doc>
 <Entries>
  <Entry>
    <RowA>Test</RowA>
    <RowB>Hello</RowB>
    <Row:C>Try to Access me </Row:C>
  </Entry>

  <Entry>
    <RowA>Try Again</RowA>
    <RowB>Hello2</RowB>
    <Row:C>Try to Access me again </Row:C>
  </Entry>

  </Entries>
</Doc>
```

Following my code, everything is working fine except Row:C

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlFile.SelectNodes("Doc/Entries/Entry");

foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodeList)
{
 String _Ok = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("RowA").InnerText;
 String _Error = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Row:C").InnerText;  // ERROR
}
```

### Following the error:

Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: could you please show your full xml?

Comment: I think you forgot to view my answer below. let me know whether it help you o not?

Answer (score 1):

You xml contains namespace so you need to use `XmlNamespaceManager` to for resolving namespace for prefixes in the XPath expression.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load(@"Path to your xml file");

        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("Row", "http://www.namespace.com/");    // <= Replace your namespace here that start with "xmlns:Row="http://www.namespace.com/"" in root of document
        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//Doc//Entries//Entry//*", ns);

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]